# Python - pyqt5 - clear selections of QTextBrowser

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I want to clear the selection in `QTextBrowser` (clear the highlighting).

```
self.textBrowser.textCursor().clearSelection()
```

Above code is not working for me.

Comment: By "clear the highlighting" do you mean you want the text not be be highlighted anymore or do you want to remove the highlighted text from the text browser?

Comment: I need the text not to be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cursor = self.textBrowser.textCursor()
cursor.clearSelection()
self.textBrowser.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

The cursor that is returned by `self.textBrowser.textCursor()` is only a copy of the textCursor being used.  To apply the changes to the text browser, you must operate on the copy and then set the text browsers textCursor to the modified version.